# Non-interactive way to create a git flow release / hotfix

Tags: macos, git, unix, terminal, git-flow

From the [docs of gitflow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Command-Line-Arguments#git-flow-hotfix-finish--fsumpkn-version) I read the following:

> #### git flow hotfix finish [-Fsumpkn]
>
> **-F** fetch from $ORIGIN before performing finish
>   **-s** sign the release tag cryptographically
>   **-u** use the given GPG-key for the digital signature (implies -s)
>   **-m** use the given tag message
>   **-p** push to $ORIGIN after performing finish
>   **-k** keep branch after performing finish
>   **-n** don't tag this release
>   Finish hotfix

Now I want to create a hotfix without user interaction so I do the following:

```
git flow hotfix finish '2.1.8' -m Hotfix
```

Despite the `-m` flag I get into the editor and I am asked to provide a tag message:

```
# File /Users/me/MyProject/.git/TAG_EDITMSG  

#
# Write a tag message
```

Am I using git flow in a wrong manner or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Besi, you have to specify the option before the hotfix branch name.

```
git flow hotfix finish -m Hotfix '2.1.8'
```

Also there can be no spaces in that name. For example 'new tag' will not work

```
git flow hotfix finish -m 'new tag' 2.1.8
```

Error:

```
flags:FATAL the available getopt does not support spaces in options
```

Following will work:

```
git flow hotfix finish -m 'new_tag' 2.1.8
```

Here is a hotfix finish git alias:

```
hf = "!_() { b=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) && git co master && git pl && git co develop && git pl && git co $b && git rebase master && h=$(echo $b | sed 's/hotfix\\///g') && git flow hotfix finish -m 'new_tag' $h && git co master && git ps && git co develop && git ps && git ps --tags && git poo $b && git br -D $b;  }; _"
```

Comment: wow nice answer, can you elaborate all the things your `hf` alias does, since it's quite lengthy and elaborate.